# Session value becomes null after Json result sent

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one method in controller which i am calling through ajax :

```
public JsonResult GetEbayOrders()
        {
            try
            {
                string EmailID = Session["EmailID"] as string;

                ------further using this emailid-----
                return json("whatever");

            }
            catch()
           {
                 return json("whatever error");
           }
        }
```

here I am calling this method on one button click through ajax and value of session through login page.

My problem is first time i am getting correct value from session.

Once i return the result eg return json("whatever"); ... from next call value of session becomes null.

I tried setting session expire to 80 minutes from Global.asax

But same thing was happening with me.

Why i am unable to retain session value???

Comment: Where do you set this session EmailID value?

Comment: @Andrei in another controller (loginController)

Comment: Using an inspector such as Fiddler, can you confirm that the session cookie is present in the headers of the AJAX request?